# Get feature names from ColumnTransformer after OHE and scaling

Tags: scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

How can I get my list of feature names from

```
ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'), cat_features),
    ("scaler", MinMaxScaler(), num_features)],
    remainder='passthrough')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return the feature names by using `encoded_feat = ct.get_feature_names_out()`